# Recursive Sorting in Python-list index out of range

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I am trying to read a file and sort the data in the array recursively. But the data is not sorted after I run the program. The text file contains many numbers, one number per line. I want to sort it in ascending order.
For example:

```
input file:
5
1
2
4
3

Expect output:
1
2
3
4
5

Actual output:
2
1
3
5
4
```

```
A=[]
f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
for row in f:
    A.append(row)
def divide(p, r):
    x = A[r]
    i =p-1
    for j in range(p,r-1):
        if (A[j] <= x):
            i+=1
            temp=A[i] 
            A[i]=A[j]
            A[j]=temp          
    temp2=A[i+1]
    A[i+1]=A[r]
    A[r]=temp2
    return i+1
    
def sort(p, r): 
    if (p < r) :
        q = divide(p,r)
        sort(p, q-1)
        sort(q+1,r)
sort(0,len(A)-1)
for a in A:
    print(a)
```

I write this program by implementing the pseudocode below, and I am confused about the purpose of the "i" variable.

```
function sort205(p, r) {
        if (p < r) {
                q = divide(p,r);
                sort205(p, q-1);
                sort205(q+1, r);
        }
}
function divide(p, r) {
        x = A[r];
        i = p-1;

        for j = p to r-1 {
                if (A[j] <= x) {
                        i += 1;
            exchange A[i] with A[j];
                }
        }
    exchange A[i+1] with A[r]
        return (i+1);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post error messages as images, but as text.

Comment: Your code opens a file, please provide a sample of the contents of that file.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the post with a sample of the contents. The problem that I run into now is that the data is not sorted after I run the program.

Comment: In case this is happens to be helpful, this appears to be [quick sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/) or something similar. There are a ton of resources on quick sort on youtube and elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines:

- in your pseudo-code `for j = p to r-1`
- in your python `for j in range(p,r-1):`

do not have the same meaning. A python `range` excludes its second argument. You probably meant to do `for j in range(p,r):`

Comment: Also, the mission of i is to get the  Index of smaller element